# Launch iPhone app automatically when it recieves remote notification

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to launch iPhone application automatically when it receives remote notification whether it is closed or in the background? I would appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance,
Sarah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer : You can't automatically launch your app when a new notification is received.

When an push notification is sent to an iPhone, the user is presented a view that is looking like an new SMS.
The user has then the option to open your application or dismiss this view.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this out:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/HandleTasks/HandleTasks.html

and read beneath Enabling Local and Push Notifications, Here you will find an answer to your question.

Then read this:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

How to implement it.

Happy Coding!

// Jakob

Comment: I'm interested in a short answer. Could this be done or not? Haven't seen any apps starting when notified. Just curious :)